# Unresolved reference in Android Studio 3 Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to use [Carto Mobile SDK](https://carto.com/engine/mobile/) but Android Studio keeps telling me `Unresolved reference: com.carto.ui.MapView`.

I have the latest Android Studio Canary, i've updated gradle and kotlin plugins and still not working.

This only happens in Android Studio 3.0 Canary, it works in Android Studio 2.3.3.

These are my gradle files:

**Project gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.mcordoba.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.carto:carto-mobile-sdk:4.0.2@aar'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: From what it looks like, Android Studio 3 doesn't support `@aar` files?
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin.html

Comment: I tought it, but i've tried other `@aar` and it worked. I'm just having problems with this one.

Comment: What if you try `transitive = true`? Even though that isn't in their documentation

Comment: Did it compile successfully anyway? Because I have same issue with Android Studio 3.0 canary 7. I have an aar library with an "Unresolved reference" error but actually I can compile without error.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add classpath `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version` to **buildscript-dependencies** of project gradle

2.Add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` after `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`of app gradle.

For me, it happens on Android studio 3.1.